# Best way to populate an array of Strings in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, uipickerview

In Objective-C, I am looking for a cleaner way to populate an array of strings.

I want to populate an array and the easiest solution appears to be hardcoding like

```
NSArray *arr =  [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First",@"Second",@"Third",nil];
```

I am using the objects (Strings) from this array for a UIPicker which I am able to do. Now, once the user selects an option (First/Second/Third) from the picker, I need a corresponding value for each of them.

Like in html we have `<option value="1">First</option>` which makes a direct correspondence between name value pair very explicit.

So, one option is to create another array and when the user selects an item in the picker get the value from second array from the corresponding position and use that.

I am wondering is that how we do it or is there a better way. Would it be better to have such static data in an xml (or something) and be able to easily read from there so the code doesn't get messed up?

Comment: You could use NSDictionary.

Answer (score 4):

Having multiple arrays that are accessed in parallel is usually a bad idea.  The simple alternative is to have one array of dictionaries where each dictionary has a name key and a value key.  If it gets more complicated, you can create a custom object instead of a dictionary and have an array of those.

Comment: Agreed. I generally do an array of dictionaries. Or sometimes, when things get hairy, I'll have an array of a custom "row" objects, where that object has properties and methods appropriate for the row.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a NSDictionary, and the syntax makes it easy to declare:

```
NSDictionary* dict= @{ @"First" : @1  , @"Second" : @2 , @"Third" : @3 };
```

Comment: Or `NSArray* array=@[@"First", @"Second", @"Third"]` which can then be retrieved as `NSString *first = array[0];`, `NSString *second = array[1];`, etc.

Comment: But the dictionary does the reverse: in pseudo-code dict["First"] is @1 .

Comment: Yeah, but when using zero-indexed controls like pickers and tables, I'm generally going from indexes to descriptions, not the other way around. Whatever the OP needs, I guess. We've walked him through the options.

Comment: BTW, you say "in pseudo-code": In the current compiler, that actually is valid syntax, `dict[@"First"]` actually now returns `@1`. (I know you know that, but many people are only now discovering the new boxing subscript syntax.)

Comment: Rather than using a NSArray I would reverse the dictionary: @{ @1: @"First" , @2:@"Second" , @3 : @"Third" }, but I guess it's a matter of personal taste.I find better to have a nil object in the case that the key is wrong, rather than causing an exception to be thrown.Btw I didn't know that syntax, I thought it was valid only in C++, I just discovered it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to use an NSDictionary (maybe NSMutableDictionary if the contents will change).  You would make the key the string value and the value whatever value you want.  Something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:firstValue, "firstString", secondValue, "secondString", etc, "etc...", nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `UIPickerView` can define your array, like you have, or use the array literal syntax:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"First", @"Second", @"Third"];
```

When you're checking what the user selected, you're probably just grabbing the `UIPickerView` method, selectedRowInComponent which returns a zero-based index. You can use that to look up the string in your index, if you want, via

```
NSInteger index = [self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
NSString *selectedString = array[index];
```

If you wanted to do a reverse lookup, you could use `indexOfObject`, which retrieves the zero-based index:

```
NSInteger index = [array indexOfObject:@"Third"];
NSLog(@"%d", index);
```

But I personally use arrays for things like table views, picker views, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly Atul, you got it right.

Go for an XML file, parse it and it will be simpler to handle.

EDIT:

The parsed xml contents can be stored in a dictionary for better accessing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to create an array.

```
NSString* string = @"first/second/third/fourth";
NSArray* arr = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] retain];
```

But to better answer your question, I would use an array of dictionaries because you can easily filter that with a simple NSPredicate to extract the value. Here's an example. First create your array of dicts by makings a dict for each string/value pair and putting them in an array...

```
NSDictionary* d1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"first", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1], nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"string", @"value", nil]];
NSDictionary* d2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:2], nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"string", @"value", nil]];
NSDictionary* d3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"third", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:3], nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"string", @"value", nil]];
NSArray* stringsAndValues = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:d1, d2, d3, nil];
```

At some point from your UIPicker you will get the string value back. Here's how NSPredicate can get you the value easily. In this case I'll assume "second" was the choice...

```
NSString* stringValue = @"second";
NSPredicate* thePred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"string == %@", stringValue];
NSArray* a = [stringsAndValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:thePred];
NSInteger value = [[[a objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"value"] integerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create plist file with array of dictionaries:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>first</string>
        <key>value</key>
        <string>first_value</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>second</string>
        <key>value</key>
        <string>second_value</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

load it with:

```
NSString *filename = @"pickerData.plist";
NSString *pathToFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle].bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
self.items = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile];
```

and then its easy to use data with picker:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.items count];
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [[self.items objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"title"];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    [self doSomethingWithValue:[[self.items objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"value"]];
}
```

Comment: plists are fragile, old, slow, and have to be put outside of the code. I wouldn't recommend this with the rise of objc-2.5 & the new literals available in clang.

Comment: OK, its slower, but much cleaner than hardcoding data.